# Prompt on exit for another program VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, exit, prompt

I would like to make a message box to promp to exit. The problem here is, I would like to get information when ANOTHER program(e.g. chrome.exe) is closing.
Is it even possible to achieve?
Thanks in advance, Kaarel.

Comment: You cannot prevent another (arbitrary) program from exiting.

Comment: Do you have source code for both programs?